# Ant (1.6.5) - How to set two properties in one <condition> or <if>

Tags: ant, properties, conditional-statements, if-statement

I am trying to assign two different strings to two different variables dependent on two booleans in Ant.

Pseudocode (ish):

```
if(condition)
   if(property1 == null)
      property2 = string1;
      property3 = string2;
   else
      property2 = string2;
      property3 = string1;
```

What I've tried is;

```
<if>
  <and>
    <not><isset property="property1"/></not>
    <istrue value="${condition}" />
  </and>
  <then>
    <property name="property2" value="string1" />
    <property name="property3" value="string2" />
  </then>
  <else>
    <property name="property2" value="string2" />
    <property name="property3" value="string1" />
  </else>
</if>
```

But i get a null pointer exception for the line containing "`<if>`". I can get it to work using `<condition property=...>` tags but can only set one property at a time. I tried using `<propertyset>` but that wasn't allowed either.

I'm new to ant as you will probably have guessed :).

Gav

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. The most straightforward is to just use two `condition` statements, and take advantage of property immutability:

```
<condition property="property2" value="string1">
    <isset property="property1"/>
</condition>
<condition property="property3" value="string2">
    <isset property="property1"/>
</condition>

<!-- Properties in ant are immutable, so the following assignments will only
     take place if property1 is *not* set. -->
<property name="property2" value="string2"/>
<property name="property3" value="string1"/>
```

This is a bit cumbersome and doesn't scale well, but for just two properties I would probably use this approach.

A somewhat better way is to use a conditional target:

```
<target name="setProps" if="property1">
    <property name="property2" value="string1"/>
    <property name="property3" value="string2"/>
</target>

<target name="init" depends="setProps">
    <!-- Properties in ant are immutable, so the following assignments will only
         take place if property1 is *not* set. -->
    <property name="property2" value="string2"/>
    <property name="property3" value="string1"/>

    <!-- Other init code -->
</target>
```

We are again taking advantage of property immutability here.  If you don't want to do that, you can use the `unless` attribute, and an extra level of indirection:

```
<target name="-set-props-if-set" if="property1">
    <property name="property2" value="string1"/>
    <property name="property3" value="string2"/>
</target>

<target name="-set-props-if-not-set" unless="property1">
    <property name="property2" value="string2"/>
    <property name="property3" value="string1"/>
</target>

<target name="setProps" depends="-set-props-if-set, -set-props-if-not-set"/>

<target name="init" depends="setProps">
    <!-- Other init code -->
</target>
```

It is important to note that the `if` and `unless` attributes of `target` only check if the property is set, not the value of the property.

Comment: Just what I needed. Thanks for having your Brain on Ant, back in '09.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**Ant-Contrib**](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) library to have access to a neat `<if><then><else>` syntax, however it will require a few download/install steps.

See this other SO question: [ant-contrib - if/then/else task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116619/apache-ant-if-then-else-task)