# ant-contrib - if/then/else task

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

I am using ant, and I have a problem with if/then/else task, (ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar).
I am running something that can be simplified with build.xml below.

I am expecting to obtain from 'ant -Dgiv=Luke' the message

```
input name: Luke
should be overwritten with John except for Mark: John
```

but it seems property "giv" is not overwritten inside if/then/else..

```
input name: Luke
should be overwritten with John except for Mark: Luke
```

Is it depending from the fact I am using equals task with `${giv}` ?
Otherwise what is wrong in my code?

build.xml CODE:

```
<project name="Friend" default="ifthen" basedir=".">

<property name="runningLocation" location="" />
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="${runningLocation}/antlib/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar" />
    </classpath>
</taskdef>

<target name="ifthen">
<echo message="input name: ${giv}" />
<if>
    <equals arg1="${giv}" arg2="Mark" />
    <then>
    </then>
    <else>
        <property name="giv" value="John" />
    </else>
</if>
<echo message="should be overwritten with John except for Mark: ${giv}" />
</target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ant Properties are very hard to overwrite (if not impossible). What you need is a [Variable](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/index.html). These are also defined in the Ant Contrib JAR.

Editing your example:

```
  <target name="ifthen"> 
    <var name="Evangelist" value="${giv}" />
    <echo message="input name: ${Evangelist}" />
    <if>
      <equals arg1="${Evangelist}" arg2="Mark" />
      <then>
      </then>
      <else>
        <var name="Evangelist" value="John" />
      </else>
    </if>   
    <echo message="should be overwritten with John except for Mark: ${Evangelist}" />
 </target>
```

Comment: Thank you DoctorRuss, As commented to ruffp, i was not aware properties are not rewrittable. I will use variables.

Comment: This is not entirely true, I was able to do the following in ant 1.8:    <loadfile property="artifact.version" srcFile="../conf/VERSION.TXT"/>
    <script language="javascript">
        <![CDATA[
            project.setProperty('artifact.version', project.getProperty('artifact.version').trim());
        ]]>       
    </script>

Comment: Ant properties are immutable. This means that once a property is set, you cannot change it's value.

Answer (score 33):

In Ant a property is always set once, after that variable is not alterable anymore.

Here follows a solution using standard Ant (without `ant-contrib`) which could be useful for the people who does not want an extra dependency.

```
<target name="test"  >
    <echo message="input name: ${param}" />

    <condition property="cond" >
        <equals arg1="${param}" arg2="Mark" />
    </condition>
</target>

<target name="init" depends="test" if="cond"> 
    <property name="param2" value="Mark" />
</target>

<target name="finalize" depends="init"> 
    <property name="param2" value="John" />
    <echo message="should be overwritten with John except for Mark: ${param2}" />
</target>
```

Comment: thank you ruffp, i prefere the other solution with variable from DoctorRuss. I was not aware that properties are not rewritable. E.g.:

<property name="color" value="red"/>
<property name="color" value="brown"/>
<echo message="color=${color}"/>

 [echo] color=red

Comment: No problem, I gave the solution according to my platform and which I was able to test (as I do not use ant-contrib). Anyway my answer could help some people who doesn't use ant-contrib like me. Cheers

Comment: Thanks. Exactly my case - needed an answer without ant-contrib. +1

Comment: Cannot be used in maven-antrun-plugin because of multiple target nodes.

Answer (score 2):

```
<project name="Friend" default="ifthen" basedir=".">

<property name="runningLocation" location="" />
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="${runningLocation}/antlib/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar" />
    </classpath>
</taskdef>

<target name="ifthen">
<echo message="input name: ${giv}" />
<if>
    <equals arg1="${giv}" arg2="Mark" />
    <then>
    </then>
    <else>
        <var name="giv" unset="true"/>
        <property name="giv" value="John" />
    </else>
</if>
<echo message="should be overwritten with John except for Mark: ${giv}" />
</target>
</project>
```

We can use `var` task to unset the property also.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but should prove handy to others searching for a solution.

to re-assign a property without using ant-contrib, use macrodef with a script.

```
<macrodef name="property-change"> 
    <attribute name="name"/>
    <attribute name="value"/>
    <sequential> 
        <script language="javascript"><![CDATA[
            project.setProperty("@{name}", "@{value}");
        ]]></script>
    </sequential> 
</macrodef>
```

then in anywhere in ant, just call this like the property tag

```
<property-change name="giv" value="John"/>
```

to Implement this in your original version of xml, it would look like this:

```
<project name="Friend" default="ifthen" basedir=".">

<property name="runningLocation" location="" />
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="${runningLocation}/antlib/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar" />
    </classpath>
</taskdef>

<target name="ifthen">
<echo message="input name: ${giv}" />
<if>
    <equals arg1="${giv}" arg2="Mark" />
    <then>
    </then>
    <else>
        <property-change name="giv" value="John" />
    </else>
</if>
<echo message="should be overwritten with John except for Mark: ${giv}" />
</target>
</project>
```

This sample is given purely as an example on writing a macro to replace the <var> command in ant-contrib.  In a situation like this one, where the <if> command is being used, it makes more sense to use <var> sinnce ant-contrib is already loaded, and <var> might be faster in processing.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Useful macro. Could be handy if you for some reason can't/don't want to use ant-contrib.

Comment: Thank you.  I use these type of scripts frequently now to enhance my ant environment without adding JAR files.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to re-assign the value of a property using the ant-contrib 'propertycopy'. This is an alternative to using ant-contrib Variables.
This way the property "giv" can be overwritten.

```
<target name="ifthen">
  <echo message="input name: ${giv}" />
  <if>
    <equals arg1="${giv}" arg2="Mark" />
    <then>
    </then>
    <else>
      <property name="tempName" value="John" />
      <propertycopy name="giv" from="tempName" override="true" />
    </else>
  </if>
  <echo message="should be overwritten with John except for Mark: ${giv}" />
</target>
```

Be aware this assumes the property tempName is not already set to a value other than 'John'.