# ant conditional execution (if-else statement in ant) and checking that a property isn't empty string

Tags: ant

Currently I have this code in ant script:

```
<target name="-pre-compile" if="${log.disabled}">
   <antcall target="remove-logs"/>
</target>
```

It's pretty self explanatory: if `log.disable=true` in properties file, then my remove-logs target will be called. Now I need to make minor changes to if/else. Pseudo-code:

```
<target name="-pre-compile">
   if("${log.disabled}")
      <antcall target="remove-logs"/>
   else if("${log.disabled.level}" != "")
      <antcall target="remove-logs-levels"/>
</target>
```

how can I write that in ant?

Also, note that all these if/them ant-contrib do not work for me:

```
<target name="test-xxx">
    <echo level="info">testing</echo>
    <if>
     <equals arg1="${log.disabled}" arg2="true" />
     <then>
       <echo message="true" />
     </then>
     <else>
       <echo message="false" />
     </else>
    </if>
</target>
```

get's me this output:

> custom_rules.xml:73: if doesn't support the nested "equals" element.

PS. Once again, I ended up writing javascript instead of wasting time with ant itself. What a crappy make replacement...

Comment: possible duplicate of [ant-contrib - if/then/else task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116619/ant-contrib-if-then-else-task)

Comment: @Jayan doesn't work for me anything that's listed there. It's just insane that simple if else takes forever to figure out how to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ant provide [conditionals](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/condition.html). Frankly using ant-contrib is easier. It provides an [if task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/if.html). See a more detailed answer in [ant-contrib - if/then/else task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116619/ant-contrib-if-then-else-task)

Comment: What bout checking that a property is defined and it's not an empty string? (I updated the title)